Server A not receiving UDP traffic on port 5060 from Server B
I have sip traffic which needs to flow bidirectionally between server A and server B on port 5060.
I have tried running netcat on both the machines
Netcat from machine A to B: 
=========================
[yy-user@yy-yy-01q scenarios]$ nc -v -u -z -w 3 96.113.48.9 5060
Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 96.113.48.9:5060.
Ncat: UDP packet sent successfully
Ncat: 1 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 2.01 seconds.

Netcat from machine B to A:
================================
root@xx-xxg-as-002:/home/admin# nc -v -u -z -w 3 76.96.x.x 5060
Connection to 76.96.x.x 5060 port [udp/sip] succeeded!

However when I try sending data from server B to A using netcat I do not see anything hitting.
I use the following command to do so
Listen on server A
nc -ul 5060

Send data from Server B to A
nc -u 76.96.x.x 5060
Hello

Could anybody tell me what could be the issue?
P.S: I have checked the firewall rules and ingress is all set to allow traffic coming to port 5060.

Run traceroute with the target port 5060 & see where it fails.

It shows packets being dropped at the 15th hop. Thanks.

Perhaps even one better than traceroute, you can also use nping --trace --udp --dest-port=5060 to do the same trace using udp packets, useful if icmp packets are being dropped
